# Looping through foreach and creating Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach

I am trying to loop through and Array of unique zones in a property data base and then create an array for the size, value and building sizes for each of those zones.

My problem is that I can create the array, but since each foreach that is loop through has the array with the same name, so the arrays totaling not just the amount with in that zone, but the amount of previously looped through zones.

For example:
Zone A should total 100
Zone B should total 200

But the Code is returning:
Zone A totals 100
Zone B totals 300 (100+200)

The issue likely falls on how the arrays, $Value, $ResSQFT and $ComSQFT, end up having the same name in each foreach loop, but I know how to rename them on the fly.

```
$Zones = "SELECT DISTINCT(ZONING_COD) FROM `ClevelandParcels`" ;

$ZonesStatus = mysqli_query($Connection, $Zones) ;
if(!$ZonesStatus)
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ZonesStatus))
{

$UniqueZones[] = array($row['ZONING_COD']);

}

echo "Zone,ParcelCount,ParcelValue,BuilingSqft,ResLivableArea,ComLeaseableArea<br>";

foreach ( $UniqueZones as $varZ ) {
  $ZoneParcelCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ClevelandParcels` WHERE ZONING_COD =     '".$varZ[0]."'" ;
  $ZoneParcelCountStatus = mysqli_query($Connection, $ZoneParcelCount) ;
  $total = mysqli_fetch_row($ZoneParcelCountStatus);

  echo $varZ[0].",".$total[0];
mysqli_free_result($ZoneParcelCountStatus);

  $ZoneParcels = "SELECT * FROM `ClevelandParcels` WHERE ZONING_COD =     '".$varZ[0]."'" ;
  $ZoneParcelsStatus = mysqli_query($Connection, $ZoneParcels) ;
  if(!$ZoneParcelsStatus)
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ZoneParcelsStatus)){
  $Value[] = $row['GROSS_CE_2'];
  $ResSqft[] = $row['TOTAL_RES_'];
  $ComSqft[] = $row['TOTAL_COM_'];
  }
    echo ",        $".array_sum($Value).",".array_sum($ResSqft).",".array_sum($ComSqft)."<br>";
    mysqli_free_result($ZoneParcelsStatus);

}
```

Comment: You need to show us some examples. Expected output? What are you currently getting? You should also include some example data for your tables so we know what data those queries would return.

Comment: You can most likely do all this with only one SQL query. Fetch all the data and then build the result in the format you want (but because of the lack of examples, I'm unclear about what the expected output should be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset your arrays before to add data in them and to compute the sum :

```
$Value=[];
$ResSqft=[];
$ComSqft=[];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ZoneParcelsStatus)){
    $Value[] = $row['GROSS_CE_2'];
    $ResSqft[] = $row['TOTAL_RES_'];
    $ComSqft[] = $row['TOTAL_COM_'];
}
```

In your code, you appends each time the values in each arrays, so your values are cumulated.

Comment: Resetting comment set me on the correct path. I ended up using unset().

Answer (score 0):

```
$Zones = "SELECT DISTINCT(ZONING_COD) FROM `ClevelandParcels`" ;

$ZonesStatus = mysqli_query($Connection, $Zones) ;
if(!$ZonesStatus)
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ZonesStatus))
{

$UniqueZones[] = array($row['ZONING_COD']);

}

echo "Zone,ParcelCount,ParcelValue,BuilingSqft,ResLivableArea,ComLeaseableArea<br>";

foreach ( $UniqueZones as $varZ ) {
  $ZoneParcelCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ClevelandParcels` WHERE ZONING_COD = '".$varZ[0]."'" ;
  $ZoneParcelCountStatus = mysqli_query($Connection, $ZoneParcelCount) ;
  $total = mysqli_fetch_row($ZoneParcelCountStatus);

  echo $varZ[0].",".$total[0];
mysqli_free_result($ZoneParcelCountStatus);

  $ZoneParcels = "SELECT * FROM `ClevelandParcels` WHERE ZONING_COD = '".$varZ[0]."'" ;
  $ZoneParcelsStatus = mysqli_query($Connection, $ZoneParcels) ;
  if(!$ZoneParcelsStatus)
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
unset($Value);
unset($ResSqft);
unset($ComSqft);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ZoneParcelsStatus)){
  $Value[] = $row['GROSS_CE_2'];
  $ResSqft[] = $row['TOTAL_RES_'];
  $ComSqft[] = $row['TOTAL_COM_'];
  }
    echo ", $".array_sum($Value).",".array_sum($ResSqft).",".array_sum($ComSqft)."<br>";
    mysqli_free_result($ZoneParcelsStatus);

}
```